# Run jest got "Unexpected string" at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

In Vuejs project, 
node version: v10.6.0

Package.json version:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.0-rc.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.0.0-rc.4",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0-rc.4",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.20",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16"
  },
```

When I run it with build in tasks,

```
"test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
```

But as I want to debug, so I run manually with node command:

```
node  node_modules/.bin/jest
```

It gives following error:

```
 FAIL  tests/unit/HelloWorld1.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    .../tests/unit/HelloWorld1.spec.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import "core-js/modules/es6.array.iterator";
                                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected string

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
```

After I added .babelrc with following content

```
{"env": {
    "development": {
        "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    },
    "test": {
        "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
}}
```

Things got a little better, It can pass the the test file without "import", once there's import, it will show a different error:

```
....tests/unit/HelloWorld1.spec.js:3
    import _interopRequireWildcard from "..../node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/es6/interopRequireWildcard";
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After struggling for a few days. Finally, I got the solution to run jest in debug mode for VueJs application.

After debuging into vue-cli-service and in turn `@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest`, I found the following code before it spawns the jest process:

```
 process.env.VUE_CLI_BABEL_TARGET_NODE = true
 process.env.VUE_CLI_BABEL_TRANSPILE_MODULES = true
```

### Solution

So the solution is very simple.

Just add these two environment variables before running the jest command. The following commands will start jest in debug mode:

```
export VUE_CLI_BABEL_TARGET_NODE=true
export VUE_CLI_BABEL_TRANSPILE_MODULES=true
./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --clearCache
node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js -i
```

#### Notes

- Make sure **DON'T**  add ".babel.rc", this will mass up VueJS babel.
- And often, you will need to run jest with the `--clearCache` option. Otherwise, the stale generated file will also mess up.
- The jest option `-i` is also important. Otherwise, the test will be running in a separate process which will not be in debug mode.

Comment: `.babel.rc` is the same as `babel.config.js`?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.

```
 FAIL  tests/unit/example.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    .../tests/unit/example.spec.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import "core-js/modules/es6.array.find";
                                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected string

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
```

Tried the answer above.[This article](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/debug-unit-tests-in-vscode-using-jest-typescript-javascript-and-of-cause-vue/60747) solved my problem.

**Solution:**

1. npm uninstall "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest"
2. deleted tests folder with all content
3. deleted jest.config.js file
4. vue add @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest
5. for VS Code use the next launch.json

```js
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [            
    {
      "name": "vscode-jest-tests",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--inspect-brk",
        "./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js",
        "test:unit",
        "--runInBand"
      ],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
      "console": "integratedTerminal",    
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "outFiles": [ "${workspaceFolder}/src/**/*.js"],
      "port": 9229
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: could you please explain why and how this would help the user? What are the key facts? what has to be changed?

Comment: @Alexander, updated my answer. Does it look better? :)

Comment: sure. much better ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to ensure your Node Environment is resolving correctly.
In my case, it would resolve to "development". Updating my `package.json` to the following resolved the issue:

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=test jest"
```

This will ensure that your babel config uses the test configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Was your test suite working before and now it's throwing this error? This is what happened to me and before going off the deep-end there is a decent chance that something is cached that is causing this.

I resolved it using: `npm test -- -u`

If that fails you should delete your `node_modules` folder and do a fresh `npm install` and then try `npm cache clean --force`.

Another useful command if you want to run the tests without cache is `npm test -- --no-cache -u`.